# How to pass a URL value from a template to a form_valid method inside a Class Based View in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I started working with django and I have come across a problem that I am not able to solve. I believe this should be easy but I cannot figure it out.

I am getting an Id from a template which I pass through a URL.

**data.html**

```
...
    <div class="container">

      <form method="GET" action="{% url 'data:next' %}">

          <input type="hidden" required name='job_id'>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Run Next</button>
          {% csrf_token %}

      </form>

    </div>
...
```

**url.py**

```
app_name = "data"

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    path('next/', RunNextView.as_view(), name='next'),
]
```

This seems to pass the job_id value to the URL as after selecting a checkbox (in this case with job_id pointing at 44) and clicking on the *Run Next* button I get to a url such as:

http://localhost:8000/data/next/?job_id=44&Some-token

which I think is good. Now I want to pass the number 44 to a class based view which is the problem and I was not able to do it.

As shown below I need the job_id in order to run the *run_next_task* task.
**How do i grab that 44 and pass it to the form_valid method inside the CBV ?**

**views.py**

```
class RunNextView(FormView):
    template_name = 'next.html'
    form_class = RunForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data:list')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('account:login'))
        else:        
            return super(RunNextView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cal = form.save(False)
        cal.user = self.request.user
        cal.save()
        cal.send_update()

        job_id = self.request.GET.get('job_id') //this way doesn't work

        run_next_task.delay(pk=cal.pk, dir=job_id)
        return redirect(self.success_url)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        for field in form.errors:
            form[field].field.widget.attrs['class'] += F" {form.error_css_class}"
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

I did countless experiments.

job_id = self.request.GET.get('job_id') inside the form_valid and pretty much every other combination. I tried using session and global variables. I tried using kwargs in many different ways such as job_id=self.kwargs['job_id'].

Non of them worked. There must be something basic and fundamental that I am missing.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you ;]

Comment: Instead of overriding `dispatch` yourself why don't you simply use the [LoginRequired mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you ! I did not even though about it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this on my own but just give it a try ;)

I added a new attribute in `__init__`
Then use it in `form_valid`.

```
class RunNextView(FormView):
    template_name = 'next.html'
    form_class = RunForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data:list')

    # Add this ↓
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.job_id = ""
        super().__init__(**kwargs) # <- You don't need put 'self' here. So, remove it.

    # Add this as well ↓
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.job_id = request.GET.get('job_id')
        super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)# <- Remove 'self' here

    # some code...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # some code...
        job_id = self.job_id #      <- Change here
        # some code...
    
    # some code...
```

**EDIT**

I am overriding the `__init__` function in this example, and I let the parent function whatever it needs to do by doing `super().__init__(**kwargs)` after I create a new attribute  `job_id`.
You can access `self.job_id` anywhere inside the class.

Comment: I tried but it does not work I get an error at super().__init__(self, **kwargs):                        line 177, in __init__
web_1       |     super().__init__(self, **kwargs)
web_1       | TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.                        Anyways would you be so kind to explain to me what are the added pieces of code doing exactly ? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove self from super(). I'll update my answer real quick with some explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I like this approach. However it partially works. In the GET method I added return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs) or else it asked for a return httpresponse. Is it correct ? Also, while self.job_id is the correct value in the GET method when using job_id=self.job_id inside the from_valid the value is None.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data with a form, you have to choose POST method not GET. add the "job_id" (or job.id. what ever u passed) to the value of the input as follow:

```
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'data:next' %}">

      <input type="hidden" value="{{job_id}}" required name='job_id'>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Run Next</button>
      {% csrf_token %}

  </form>
```

then in view, define a post method:

```
class RunNextView(FormView):
     def post(self,request):
         # Since name='job_id'
         posted_id=request.POST["job_id"]
```

Comment: Interesting, but after you define the post method how do you pass posted_id to the form_valid method ? and what should the post method return ?

Comment: @Enric `FormView` and similar generic views only consider the form to be submitted in case of a POST request. Considering you save data you should be using a POST request anyway. Next `self.request.POST["job_id"]` would give you what you want in the `form_valid` method no need to override `post`.